# Morris.js area chart issue

Tags: asp.net, graph, charts, area

I am working on Morris.js graph of Bootstrap theme (http://wrapbootstrap.com/preview/WB063H186)

Following is in example of Area chart
http://jsbin.com/otaxef/115/embed?js,output

If you look at the result of the above graph, you can see value of b is 90,65,40...respectively

If you can see the result at right side you can see its rendering at 190,140....points

May I know the reason for that?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's placing are b on top of area a so it appears that area b is at 190 when it's really at 90 (i.e. 190 - 100 or 190 - a)...